# C# Selenium ChromeDriver - how to suppress Print Preview, pdf

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I know there are many questions like this, but from my research there is nothing that solves the issue of suppressing PDF viewing in Chrome, with the current state of the C# Chromedriver.

I can get the test to work manually if I disable the Chrome PDF Viewer plugin and do a --disable-print-preview in the command line, but I have not managed to get anything to work in Selenium.

I've tried 
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.plugins_disabled", "Chrome PDF Viewer");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-print-preview");

and many other variations including adding download.default_directory, suppressing download.prompt_for_download, etc etc,

The constructor for ChromeDriver that used Capabilities no longer seems to work. Also everyone else talking about PDFs wants the preview to happen in the tab, the opposite of what I want. I'd like the PDF to download the same as it does when you manually disable the plugin.

Comment: any solution found for it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.plugins_disabled", new[] {
                "Adobe Flash Player",
                "Chrome PDF Viewer"
            });
var driver = new ChromeDriver(path + @"\chrome-driver", chromeOptions);
```

Comment: How would I then print?